# CSS animation - slide line in from left to right next to title

Tags: javascript, css, animation, jquery-animate

Wondering if I could get some help/direction...

Basically, I'm building my portfolio website. Here's work in progress, it's not finished! 
https://reenaverma.github.io/

Basically, when you scroll down the page, you'll see a grey line moves from left, to the middle of the screen.  It should basically be an animation to accompany the title on scroll.

I basically want the grey line to stop, at the beginning of each title.  So for 'about reena', it should stop before "a", (not underneath).

I wanted to know the best way to achieve this?  The relevant code so far is below.  I got some of this off google and stackoverflow already.

I suppose I could drop the title before a div, (so the animation sits in a div on the left of the title).  And use animate.js fadein/slidein.  But I just wanted to know if there was a better/right way to do this?

**HTML**

```
<section class="section-white">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="flex-grid">
            <div class="col-white">
              <h2><span>about reena</span>
                <div class="line"></div>
              </h2>
              <!-- <div id="trainMotion">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/uKxkshD.png" alt="" 
                class="line">

              <p>A Full Stack Developer etc etc etc...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.line {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 3px;
 background-color: #ccc;
 width: 150px;
 left: -300px;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
  const trainPosition = Math.round($(window).scrollTop() / 
$(window).height() * 100);
$('.line').css('transform','translateX('+(trainPosition-30)+'%)');
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the `<h2>` container into two parts. And add the animation container adjacent to the title making sure that the animation is restricted to that container only.

I am adding a [codepen link](https://codepen.io/gandhi_rahul/pen/XqpNGB?editors=1100) which might help. [Link](https://codepen.io/gandhi_rahul/pen/XqpNGB?editors=1100)

[image: codepen screenshot]

In this scenario, I restricted the width of the animation container. You can synchronise the timing with the JS.

Comment: ok thank you, i'll give this a go.  So basically keep the line, on the left in a div and then on scroll effect through js...

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to play around with the values at `transform: translateX(-50%);` in your CSS and `+(trainPosition-30)+'%)` in your JS to achieve the destination coordinates that are ideal for your project. Where your `translateX` value is the starting position then on scroll you're adding an additional 30%.

I don't know that this would be the cleanest option, but you can experiment with media queries to ensure that on all screen sizes it'll reach the position you want.

Comment: I don't think the transform in CSS does anything, when i removed it it still worked as normal...  left: -300 sets the starting position....